# TryCasting to TypeOf in VB

Tags: vb.net, types, casting

How come TryCast won't accept t as Type?

```
Private Async Function DeSerialize(FilePath As String, t As Type) As Task(Of Object)
  Dim ReadStream = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FilePath)
  Dim Sarjoittaja As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(GetType(UITextsClass))
  Return TryCast(Sarjoittaja.ReadObject(ReadStream), t)
End Function
```

Still not quite there yeat:

```
Public Async Function DeSerialize(Of T)(FilePath As String) As Task(Of T)
  Dim ReadStream = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FilePath)
  Dim Sarjoittaja As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(T) 'T' is a Type and cannot be used as an expression
  Return DirectCast(Sarjoittaja.ReadObject(ReadStream), T)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TryCast` operator as well as `CType` and `DirectCast` operate on a type name rather than an instance of `System.Type`.

If your infrastructure allows it, convert this method to a generic method.

```
Private Async Function DeSerialize(Of T)(FilePath As String) As Task(Of T)
 'Read and Deserialize
 Dim ReadStream = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FilePath)
 Dim Sarjoittaja As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(GetType(UITextsClass))
 Return TryCast(Sarjoittaja.ReadObject(ReadStream), T)
End Function
```

**Re: comment**

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can get the type that was passed in using the `GetType()` operator.

```
Dim t As Type = GetType(T)
Dim Sarjoittaja As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(t)
```

Comment: Thank you. We are getting close. How about replacing the `GetType(UITextsClass)` with something more dynamic? Replacing it with 'T' did not work (see edit with error message as comment on the original post above).

Comment: No go 'TypeOf' expects 'Is'

Comment: Sorry, my VB is a little rusty. I meant `GetType()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for using a Generic Type is a little off:- you need to define the generic type before the arguments and return this type as well like this:

```
Private Async Function DeSerialize(Of T)(FilePath As String) As Tasks.Task(Of T)
    'Read and Deserialize
    Dim ReadStream = Await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FilePath)
    Dim Sarjoittaja As New Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer(GetType(UITextsClass))
    Return TryCast(Sarjoittaja.ReadObject(ReadStream), T)
End Function
```

See the [docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246.aspx) for more info

Comment: Beat me to it by less than 10 seconds... >.<